# Why is $E[2]$ of $E: y^2 = x^3 - p$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ramified?

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, local-field

I would greatly appreciate if someone could explain me the following. 
Given an elliptic curve $E: y^2 = x^3 - p$ over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, I am struggling to show why $E[2]$ is ramified. I would greatly appreciate any comments or suggestions on how to start this. Thank you.

Comment: (Tiny typo: Presumably you mean $y^2=x^3-p$? The curve you've written isn't an elliptic curve - or at best, it's a degenerate one...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nonzero points in $E[2]$ are the $(\alpha,0)$ where $\alpha$ runs through the cube roots of $p$. Each $\alpha$ has $1/3$ of the valuation of $p$, so it apparent that $\Bbb Q_p(\alpha)$ is totally ramified of degree three over $\Bbb Q_p$.

Comment: Could you possibly explain how $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is ramified implies why the inertia subgroup does not act trivially on $E[2]$ (because this is the definition of unramified/ramified I have...)?

Comment: The inertia group acts non-trivially on proper ramified extension, so acts non-trivially on $E[2]$ here.